# Center two Text Elements of different Heights in a Container

Tags: html, css, position, center

I have a **container with a small fixed height** and a width of 100%. It is `display:block`.

Inside there are **two similar elements containing text**. They have different `font-size`s and are floated - one to the left and the other to the right.

[image: vertical center skectch]

HTML

```
<header>
    <h1 class="right">Title</h1>
    <h2 class="left">Slogan</h2>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header{ position:fixed; width:100%; height:5em; }
header h1{ font-size:3em; margin:0; }
header h2{ font-size:2em; margin:0; }
```

I don't want to use `display:table-cell`. And I can't use `line-height` because I am only using `em` and not `px` and `font-size`s of the text elements are different.

**How can I vertically center the text elements?**

Comment: I want to be able the change the height of the container. The text elements should always be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write **line-height** same as `height`. Write like this:

```
header{ position:fixed; width:100%; height:5em;line-height:5em; }
```

Comment: he said he cant put line-height.

Comment: Genius ;-) I don't want to put `line-height`s on the text elements. But putting it on the container is great. Didn't know that before.

Comment: @sharethis why you don't want line-height

Comment: I don't want to put exact line height in the text elements because they have different font-sizes. And line-height is a relative value to the font-size. So I would need to calc it. But line-height inherited from the the container is great.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I think something like this might work:

```
header h1 { font-size:3em; margin:0; float:right; top:50%; position:relative; margin-top:-0.5em;}
header h2 { font-size:2em; margin:0; float:left; top:50%; position:relative; margin-top:-0.5em;}
```

[EDIT] I've not got enough privileges to be able to comment yet, but Sandeep's reply works because the `line-height` is inherited by the child elements, therefore you are indirectly giving them a `line-height`.

Comment: Thanks, should also work. But I am just happy with sandeep's solution.

Comment: @sharethis: See my edit above. Just in case you hadn't noticed this :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a site title and slogan, elements which usually do not change frequently, I would simply set different margin-top distances for each element until they line up visually the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're measuring font-sizes in EMs, which leads me to assume the text can grow and shrink. You could use a JS solution, like this jQuery:

```
$('h1, h2').each(function(){
    var headerHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    $(this).css('margin-top', '-' + headerHeight / 2 + 'px');
});
```

This would accompany some CSS, like this:

```
h1, h2 {position: absolute; top: 50%;}
```